# R data read as characters

Tags: r

I am trying to read a data table into R. The data contains:

- two columns with numeric values (continuous),
- 1556 columns with either 0 or 1, and
- one last column with strings, representing two groups (group A and
  group B).

Some values are missing, and they are replaced with either `?` or some spaces and then `?`. As a result, when I read the table into R, the numbers were read as characters.

For example, if Data[1,1]=125, when I write `is.numeric(Data[1,1])` I get FALSE. I want to turn all the numbers into numbers, and I want all the `?` (with or without spaces before) into missing values. Do not know how to do this. Thank you! (I have 3279 rows).

Comment: You may  consider reading the dataset using `fread` from `data.table` (as you have a lot of columns) which also has `na.strings` argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the `na.strings` argument of `?read.table` to be `na.strings = c("?", "?.")`. Use that inside the `read.table()` call when you read the data into R. It should then by recognised correctly. Since you also have some spaces in your data, you could additionally use the `strip.white = TRUE` argument inside the `read.table` call.